# Flutter SingledChildScrollView > Stack > Positioned is glitches on Scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Stack` as its first element. The `Stack` contains two containers. The second one is positioned at `bottom: 0.0` using a `Positioned`.

I highly simplified my view for this post to focus only on this issue. When I scroll slowly, you can see that the white container is "glitching" and you see a line that is the bottom of the first child of the stack.

Here is the view:

[image]

Not that's what happen when I scroll down, I have no clue why it's glitching like that:

[image]

**View:**

```
return Container(color: Colors.white, child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    HeaderComponent(),
    Container(height: 600, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)
  ]
)));
```

**Header Component**

```
class _HeaderComponentState extends State<HeaderComponent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(height: 245.0, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, color: Colors.red),
        Positioned(bottom: 0.0, child: Container(height: 40.0, width: 
           MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, color: Colors.white)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that, just add bottom padding 0.2 at first child.

```
class HeaderComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
            height: 245.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.2),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.red),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            child: Container(
                height: 40.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.white)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but still this is a very hacky way of solving it. I wonder what's going on on the Flutter side. Btw for better readability its better if you post only one answer that you edit over time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know root cause. But Positoned's 'bottom: 0.0' occurs upper container's background color a little during scrolling.
So when I set 'bottom: -0.2', this problem is not occured.
But it does not looks cool...

```
class HeaderComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
            height: 245.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.red),
        Positioned(
            bottom: -0.2,
            child: Container(
                height: 40.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.white)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see. I just tried your code but doing this my white container appears on top of the red view, just like if i specified `top: 0.0` with my previous code.

Comment: Oh sorry I will check it.

Comment: let me know. Also yes I can fix it by putting `bottom: -0.02`

Comment: 'Positioned.fill'  with before code, it has a same symptom....
hm...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another solution like below.

```
class HeaderComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 245.0,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, color: Colors.red),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 40.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But with this code, the second container won't be on top of the first one? It will be below ?

Comment: Yes, second child will be below.
Do you want to let second child on first child with opacity?
If second child is on first child without opacity, I think it is same.

Comment: I need it to be on top of it, thats with i was using a stack